# Changing .net Membership ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I need to change the connection string that the .net Membership API uses.
Basically the API loads the connection string from app.config on the first time you are calling it.

Does anyone knows how can I dynamically tell the API to use a different connection string?

```
<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="6545"
         minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
         passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="RoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="RoleProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
         connectionStringName="MySqlConnection" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
</system.web>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection"
       connectionString=".." 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

EDIT:

Solved - > [Set connection string of membership dynamically from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838669/set-connection-string-of-membership-dynamically-from-code)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own custom membership provider code (this is not as complicated as it sounds).  You need to provide a class that inherits from SqlMembershipProvider, and then add an overriden initialise method:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
    // Get your new connnection string name and then overwrite the base here:
    config.Item["connectionStringName"] = "MyNewConnectionStringName";

    base.Initilize(name, config);
}
```

Then in your web.config, for the membership section, you need to put your new custom type in the 'type' attribute.  This requires you to get your new connection string from the ConnectionStrings application section.

You may also need to also override the RoleProvider and the ProfileProvider depending on your requirements.

P.S. Code quickly translated on the fly from VB.net, apologies if there are a few syntax errors.

---

In the web.config, you must fully qualify your custom reference, something like (query from comments):

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
type="zTester.tempMemebership, zTester, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" ... etc
```

Comment: Created the new class, but it doesnt recognize the propertie 'Item' in config or the 'Initilize'

Comment: Have you inherited from SqlMembershipProvider?

Comment: Yea added the code, I see in the docs that Item property should exist, what am i forgetting :/

Comment: I think i managged to deal with this one but now it says: "Could not load type 'zTester.tempMemebershipProvider' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."

Comment: I would guess that the way you have configured this in your web.config is incorrect - have you got your own namespace in the configuration section?

Comment: Where exactly do you mean?I added it offcurse in the type (Added Edit please see)

Comment: You need to qualify your type with your own namespace, otherwise it searches System.Web.  Will update answer.

Comment: I get 'Could not load type 'zTester.tempMemebership' from assembly 'zTester, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral''. By the way, the type should be loaded from a lib right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45277/discussion-between-susparsy-and-paddy)