# cannot get Item in NameValueCollection to be recognized

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0

I am trying to set my config from code according to this post [Changing .net Membership ConnectionString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114512/changing-net-membership-connectionstring)

In this post, it has this code:

```
public override void Initialize(string name, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection config)
{
    // Get your new connnection string name and then overwrite the base here:
    config.Item["connectionStringName"] = "MyNewConnectionStringName";

    base.Initilize(name, config);
}
```

I made my class as such:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace WebUsers
{
  internal class MembershipOverride : SqlMembershipProvider
  {
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection configx)
    {
      // Get your new connnection string name and then overwrite the base here:
      configx.Item["connectionStringName"] = "MyNewConnectionStringName";
      base.Initilize(name, config);
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot get Item or Initialize to be recognized.

It is doing this:

[image]

Anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot get Item or Initialize to be recognized.

There is a typo. You call `base.Initilize` instead of `base.InitiAlize`.

To access the collection element, try just

```
configx["connectionStringName"] = "MyNewConnectionStringName";
```

Comment: thank you, that did fix the issue with Initialize but not item :(

Comment: @ErocM Updated. Try without `.Item`.