# ASP.NET manage multiple DB connections

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection, database-connection

I didn't find any useful information about this, so I will try here.

My approach is, to have different db connections on my test server and on my life server.

Right now I have one connection String

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="my_life" ... />
  </connectionStrings>
```

*Important note* I had to provide the name of my string to the **AspNetSqlMembershipProvider** and **AspNetSqlRoleProvider**

```
<roleManager>
      <providers>
        <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
             connectionStringName="my_life" ... />
         </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

Is there a way to handle the db connection via env variable or maybe url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really prefer to use [DB Aliases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1620/how-to-setup-and-use-a-sql-server-alias/) if you want only ip address of your db to be diferent. If you want to have different web.config with different configurations by environment you can use web.config transformations.

Check [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Application Project Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(VS.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can maintain multiple connection strings in a XML file with unique reference id and read this file to get the connection string dynamically in your code where ever you want.

Sample like

```
<ConnectionString>
<Connection>
<Id></Id>
<ConString></ConString>
</Connection>
</ConectionString>
```

Comment: how to pass them to roleManager?

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838669/set-connection-string-of-membership-dynamically-from-code